# datetime in python doesn't recognise "jul"?

Tags: python, list, date, datetime

I have a list of dates in the format: 
dates = ['28/May/2012','30/Jul/2012','2/Jul/2012']

I can convert dates[0] to datetime using:

```
xdates = []
for i in dates:
    dates_formatted = i.translate(None, '/')
    d = datetime.strptime(dates_formatted, '%d%B%Y')
    xdates.append(d)

xdates
```

However, when it gets to the second item on my list "30/Jul/2012" it doesn't like it. I'm assuming it expects "july" instead of "jul"?

"ValueError: time data '30Jul2012' does not match format '%d%B%Y'"

If so, is there a neat way around this? or will i have to replace each jul with july for each item in the list? (or am i completely wrong!)

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior check difference of `%B` and `%b`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%B` is the month's full name. The abbreviated name is `%b`. This works:

```
d = datetime.strptime(dates_formatted, '%d%b%Y')
```

A really useful reference to these formats is http://strftime.org/.